# Refresh token with Keycloak

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, openid-connect, keycloak

I use [JWT for Client Authentication][1] in [Keycloak][2]:

```
 POST /token.oauth2 HTTP/1.1
 Host: as.example.com
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 grant_type=authorization_code&
 code=vAZEIHjQTHuGgaSvyW9hO0RpusLzkvTOww3trZBxZpo&
 client_assertion_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3A
 client-assertion-type%3Ajwt-bearer&
 client_assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.
 eyJpc3Mi[...omitted for brevity...].
 cC4hiUPo[...omitted for brevity...]
```

I get :

```
assess_token
refresh_token
token_type
expires_in
```

When I try to refresh token I send `refresh_token` itself, grant type `refresh_token` and get:

````
    "error": "unauthorized_client",
    "error_description": "INVALID_CREDENTIALS: Invalid client credentials"
}```

when I specify `client_id` I get:

```{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "Parameter client_assertion_type is missing"
}```

If I specify `client_assertion_type` I get error that `client_assertion` itself is missing, so I literally have to provide parameters I provided when retrieved access token.

How that refreshing process actually should work?


  [1]: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-jwt-bearer-12#section-2.2
  [2]: https://www.keycloak.org
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could very well be a limitation or policy defined by Keycloak. RFC7523 (JWT for Client Authentication) does allow to enable client credentials when JWT authentication is present. This is highlighted from [3.1.  Authorization Grant Processing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7523#section-3.1)

> JWT authorization grants may be used with or without client
> authentication or identification.  Whether or not client
> authentication is needed in conjunction with a JWT authorization
> grant, as well as the supported types of client authentication, are
> policy decisions at the discretion of the authorization server.
> However, if client credentials are present in the request, the
> authorization server MUST validate them.

So even if [Keycloak support JWT client authentication](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.1/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/client-authentication.html), it may still require client credentials to be present in the refresh token request. But also, it could be a limitation from their end.

Additionally, token refresh is defined through [RFC6749 - The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749). According to it's [section 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-6), refresh token request must contain client credentials when client is a confidential client (simply a client which was created with id and a password). If what you seen is not a limitation, then guess Keycloak adhere to RFC6749 and require you to send client credentials in token refresh request.

Comment: yes, unfortunately client type is confidential and force us sending all creds. thanks a lot!